# laravel - if the database changes, send notification

Tags: laravel

if any data has been inserted into the database, I want to alert message to another page. How can I do it?

This is the controller page:

```
public function insertFunction(Request $request) {
    $insert = New ExampleTable;
    $insert->test_id = $request->id;
    $insert->save();
    // after this i want to send notification to the another page(panel.blade.php) without refreshing
}
```

This is the `panel.blade.php` where I want to see the notification:

```
<script> 
    // if notification comes, do it
    alert("notification came");
</script>
```

I'm using mysql. If you help me I will be glad, thanks.

Comment: Learn [ask] as we do not create your code for you, we help you with your code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want real time notification, the best practice would be to use the [broadcast](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/broadcasting) functionality of Laravel.

Most likely, you will end up using something like [pusher](https://pusher.com).

However, you could make a custom java-script loop that continuously asks your endpoint if there has been any updates, but that would be bad practice and is not recommended.

This is an [article](https://christoph-rumpel.com/2020/11/laravel-real-time-notifications) that I found helpful. Good luck!